Programming Quest-2 vr-headset with A-frame: How to point the src of a <video> element to a video file in Internal shared storage "Movies" folder?
I'm using the Aframe library to program a Meta Quest 2 using html and javascript.  I used a usb cable from my windows PC to the headset to preload a video file on to the headset's Internal shared storage, into the preexisting "Movies" folder:  "my_video_file.webm".  I have this in html:
But this gives me an http 404 not found error.
Is there a way for me to set the src attribute so that it accesses that video file stored locally?
Or is there any other way to store video files locally on the vr-headset and access them via Aframe so that I don't have to download them from the web server?
